# How to filter out the stocks whose price has been increasing for 3 consecutive days

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

I want to filter out the the strong performance stocks among a bunch of companies by the attribute of price increasing for 3  consecutive days.  Below the code so far. Appreciate if any help.

In other words, i want get a list of stock names whose price has been been increasing continuously for the past 3 days.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas_datareader as web

tick = ['AMZN', 'AAPL', 'NFLX', 'XOM', 'T']
df = web.get_data_yahoo(tick,
                           start = '2020-01-01',
                           end = '2020-12-16')['Adj Close']
```

Comment: Could you please clarify your requirement?

Comment: i want get a list of stock names whose price has been been increasing continuously for the past 3 days. thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can compare if the difference is increasingly changing by using a `rolling` approach:

```
increase_table = df.rolling(3).apply(lambda x: np.all(np.diff(x) > 0)).astype('boolean')
```

Output for the first 10 rows:

```
Symbols      AMZN   AAPL   NFLX    XOM      T
Date                                         
2020-01-02   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>
2020-01-03   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>
2020-01-06  False  False  False  False   True
2020-01-07   True  False  False  False   True
2020-01-08  False  False  False  False   True
2020-01-09  False   True  False  False  False
2020-01-10  False   True  False  False  False
2020-01-13  False   True  False  False  False
2020-01-14  False  False  False  False  False
2020-01-15  False  False  False  False  False
```

---

I didn't get the logic from what you want to get your lists. But something useful here is to verify how much consecutive-3-days is increasing per stock:

```
increase_table.sum()
```

which returns:

```
Symbols
AMZN    74
AAPL    59
NFLX    57
XOM     40
T       58
dtype: int64
```

so that we know that "AMZN" has more days with increasing in the last 3 days.

---

**Note:** For correct interpretation, the `True` values here is telling us that the last two values and itself (current value; total = 3 values) are increasing. To correctly place the `True` values to indicate that the last three rows (and the row itself) are increasing, just do `increase_table.shift()`.

Comment: Appreciate for your reply. It works for my problem~

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
def compute_consecutive_increase(tick_data, window_size=3):
    
    # Make sure the time series is sorted by date (assuming that date is the index)
    tick_data = tick_data.sort_index()
    
    # Put side-by-side the comparison of current day ('t-0') with previous day ('t-1'),
    # then 't-1' with 't-2', etc.
    shifted_comparison = pd.concat({f't-{i}': tick_data.shift(i) > tick_data.shift(i+1) \
        for i in range(window_size)}, axis=1)
    
    # Collapse horizontally (by date) and return True for each row where all values
    # are True, i.e. all last 'window_size' days have positive increases
    return shifted_comparison.all(axis=1)

df.transform(compute_consecutive_increase)

# To collapse for each tick, if there's at least one 3-day sequence with increases
df.transform(compute_consecutive_increase).any()
```

Comment: thx for your solution. But when i run this code, the result is not correct. Take AMAZON for instance, it has been increasing for the past 3 consecutive days but the result returns false.

Comment: @algo111111 I've checked again, not sure what you're referring to, if the last 3 days you're referring to are Dec 14th to 16th, then yes, AMZN is increasing for all these 3 days:

2020-12-11=3116.419922, 2020-12-14=3156.969971, 2020-12-15=3165.120117, 2020-12-16=3240.959961

And the line `df.transform(compute_consecutive_increase)` returns `True` for 2020-12-16, is this what you're seeing too?